# Android studio taking very long time for build project After Android Studio Arctic Fox Update

Tags: android, android-studio

look how much time it's taking just for normal build
Please help me out if you got Any solution

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have noticed the builds taking longer than normal after refactoring. Not sure if it's due to a 30+ file project, or if it is Artic Fox. My memory is telling me it is Artic Fox, but I can not say for sure. May be worth noting the I also upgraded my project to API 31, from 30.

Comment: @JohnGlen Thanks for your comment. You're right it happened because of the API update.

Answer (score 0):

My first build after update took about 6 mins and it got quicker later on, so I guess the first few builds might take some time. Later on its all good.
Its recommended to restart android studio after the first build is complete.